# jQuery - Selectors, nested children

Tags: jquery

I am using the slideToggle function to show a div that is within a div.
The div that is being toggled also contains a form with checkboxes. Whenever the checkboxes are checked the div slides closed.

How can I use my selectors better to avoid this?

the JS

```
$('.head').click(function(){       
        $(this).find('div.body').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
```

the HTML

```
<div class="head">
Show Content 1
<div class="body" style="display:none;">Content</div>​
</div>
```

Comment: *How can I use my selectors better to avoid this?* To avoid what? Closing the div when the checkboxes are checked?

Comment: What is the problem with `$(this)`?

Comment: nevermind, I just figured it out. The problems was with the nesting. sorry, long day

Comment: @VisioN. ohhh, then you're still a live, long time no see.

Comment: @gdoron Taking small dozes of SO is more helpful ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you've attached a click event listener to your div with the head class. All events bubble up the document object model so clicking anywhere inside of the "head div" will cause the event to fire. There are several ways to solve the issue. You can stop the event propagation of your input elements or you can restructure your document. I would prefer the restructuring to keep from having to stop propagation for everything contained within the div.

```
<div class="head">Show Content 1</div>
<div class="body" style="display:none;">Content</div>

$('.head').click(function(){       
    $(this).next('div.body').slideToggle();
    return false;
});​
```

There are more elegant jQuery and DOM solutions, but hopefully this will give you the idea.